# sub-domain masks with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, masking, yammer

We have just created a Yammer Account and the link to our account is link this https://www.yammer.com/mydomain.org.uk/

I want to hide the word `Yammer.com` and mask it with the word `social` so the domain will look life this.

`social.mydomain.org.uk`

So If someone will open social.mydomain.org.uk it will show https://www.yammer.com/mydomain.org.uk/ but the address will be masked by social.mydomain.org.uk

I'm not very technical but I know how to change DNS and can upload htaccess file if someone can kindly tell me what exactly am I suppose to write in the file.

Answer (score 0):

you can't solve this problem with htaccess.

one workaround would be to install a index.html with a html-frameset in it, which points the browser to yammer.com/… (example here: http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/frames_example_2.html, you need to adapt the example a little bit)

caveat for this solution: you can't copy a deep url from the browser address bar and i don't know if yammer.com permits this solution.

Answer (score 0):

htaccess would not be the best tool for this job. You can take it up steam to the dns level and throw a 302 or Web forwarding rule which most registrars will let you do from their interface with a CNAME.

HTHs
//P